# My page reloads when i click on a button

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem. I'm trying to make a register dialogue with multiple forms.

I start with the welcome div and when i click the button it goes perfectly fine to the first setupbox. Now when i want to go from the second to the third setupbox it just refresh my page. What am i doing wrong here?

This is my button that does the refreshing.

```
  <div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button gotoThird" value="Get started!">
</div>
```

This is my JS file.

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {


    $(function() {
    $(".fadeIn").fadeIn(1500);
    });

    $("#getStartedButton").click(function() {
        $(".fadeIn").hide();
        $(".setupBox-second").fadeIn(1500);
    });  

    $(".gotoThird").click(function() {
        $(".setupBox-second").hide();
        $(".setupBox-third").fadeIn(1500);
    });  

});
```

Hope y'all can help me out :)

Answer (score 1):

Add preventDefault https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

pass in the event "e" and prevent its default action

```
$("#getStartedButton").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default action of clicking an a tag.
        $(".fadeIn").hide();
        $(".setupBox-second").fadeIn(1500); 
    ));
```

Comment: Nope, it won't help. There is simply no default action for button click, so nothing to prevent.

Comment: You might need to use a <button> element instead?

Answer (score 0):

Change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`